# How can I specify two BuildRequires items in a specfile where the 2nd relies on the 1st being installed?

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

I am trying to build an RPM, which has two BuildRequires items; the first is a repository RPM, which is the source of the 2nd RPM.  The second BuildRequires item is obviously dependent on the first repository one being installed but the two are being installed together hence the second RPM is not sourced from the required repository as it is not yet installed.  Can I configure so the first is installed before trying to install the second?

```
BuildRequires:  source-for-second-rpm
BuildRequires:  second-rpm

....

Getting requirements for /root/rpmbuild/SPECS/stuff.spec
 --> source-for-second-rpm
 --> 1:second-rpm     < this is not the correct version as above not yet installed

....

Installing:
 second-rpm                sourced-from-other-repository!
 source-for-second-rpm     sourced-correctly
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that the dependencies are not correctly set in those two rpms.

Normally **second-rpm** should `Requires` **source-for-second-rpm**, which is obviously not the case. If those requirements were set correctly, the rpms would have been installed in the correct order.

Comment: The first is a repository from where I can retrieve the required version of the 2nd RPM.  It's not necessarily a requirement.

Comment: Thinking further, moving second-rpm installation to the %prep section, i.e. yum-config-manager --enable <source-for-second-rpm-repo> && yum install -y second-rpm is a way to do it.

Comment: I'm afraid you are not using spec files the way they are meant to be used.
You should have the spec file inside your sources and build that way...

Comment: What you say is correct.  I'm working in CICD environment that currently doesn't have the correct setup so I''m working around some issues.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such provision for this yet in RPM SPEC files.
Still you can do one thing:-

a) Install the source-for-second-rpm first.
b) Install this RPM which you just made.

Note:- Don't mention the *source-for-second-rpm* as a dependency of your RPM.

Lets say I want to build a RPM named abc.rpm and it has a dependency on python36.
Now python36 packages are available in epel-release repository.

So, you need to do the following:-
a) yum install epel-release
b) yum install abc.rpm